# Yii2 DateValidator: как передать пустое значение?

Tags: php, yii2

Вот так определяю валидатор:

```
        ['date', 'date',
            'format'             => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
            'timestampAttribute' => 'date',
        ],
```

атрибут date **не является required**, и тем не менее, если его не отправить, то

```
[
  {
    "field": "date",
    "message": "Неверный формат значения «Дата»."
  }
]
```

как быть в такой ситуации? Нужно, чтобы атрибут date не менялся, если передано пустое значение (или не передано вообще).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно указать параметр **skipOnEmpty** = true.

```
['date', 'date',
            'format'             => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
            'timestampAttribute' => 'date',
            'skipOnEmpty'        =>  true
        ],
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Только добавлю, что 'skipOnEmpty' по документации - булево.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Механическая ошибка. Поправил